# Inserting multiple rows with same foreign key results in "constraint failed"

Tags: android, foreign-keys, constraints, ormlite

I have a class `Contact` and a class `PhoneNumber`. Inside `PhoneNumber` class, I have the attribute:

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = "contact_id")
private Contact mContact;
```

and the `contact_id` in `Contact` class is this:

```
@DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "contact_id", allowGeneratedIdInsert = false)
private Integer m_id;
```

When I try to insert a new `PhoneNumber` to the database with the same `contact_id` value, it always returns a `constraint_failed` error.

Should it happen? Am I not able to insert multiple rows with same foreign key? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show some of your insert code as a small block?  Any what version of ORMLite are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This should happen. You implemented one-to-one relationship, but you need one-to-many. In your class you have single contact for phone number, but db stores multiple contacts for one phone number. That makes no sense. So, you should use List contacts, instead of Contact contact. Then inserting multiple contacts with the same id will work.